# RSS though JSON

Tags: android, rss

I want to do an RSS reader with a help of JSON in Android. I'm new to JSON at all, so now I basically read about it and try to do some examples. 
What I'm askins is: "Are there any information about JSON in Android and RSS in together? In Android of course." I couldn't find any clear explanation how to do that on the Internet.

Comment: RSS is a data format. JSON is a data format. They each solve the same type of problem. If you choose one, you can not also choose the other one.

Comment: That sounds good. Can you give me some examples, links, please?

Answer (score 3):

RSS is already a dataformat ( XML based ).
So you can forget about JSON and parse the XML directly.

Here is a nice resource that lets you **parse XML into a Listview**:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/

(or a JSON one )

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/